# I am able to create a dropdown menu but I want it to be within the GUI of the main program in python

Tags: python, user-interface, drop-down-menu, tkinter

So I currently have my main program that works fine, but I want a dropdown menu to appear within the GUI. When I try some coding though, it makes the new dropdown menu appear inside a new window when I want it to appear next to some text. Is it possible to embed the dropdown menu into the GUI?

This is the code I use to create the menu:

```
def f2createmenu():

    master = Tk()

    variable = StringVar(master)
    variable.set("one") # default value

    w = OptionMenu(master, variable, "one", "two", "three")
    w.pack()

    mainloop()
```

In the GUI, I have two frames. This is taken from the second frame and as you can see I have called the subroutine, I am just unsure of how to make it embed into the GUI, not as a seperate window.

```
#Frame 2 (Query) Heading Buttons
labelspare=Label(f2, text =" ").grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(W, E))
f2button1=Button(f2,  text="Order",command = CurrentOrders).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W,E), ipadx = 20, ipady = 10, padx = 5, pady = 5)
f2button2=Button(f2,  text="Customer",command = CurrentOrders).grid(column=3, row=2, sticky=(W, E), ipadx = 20, ipady = 10, padx = 5, pady = 5)
f2button3=Button(f2,  text="Products",command = CustomerDetails).grid(column=4, row=2, sticky=(W, E), ipadx = 20, ipady = 10, padx = 5, pady = 5)
f2labelspare=Label(f1, text =" ").grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=(W, E))
f2labelspare=Label(f1, text =" ").grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=(W, E))
text2=Text(f2, width = 125, height = 42, wrap = WORD)


f2entryone=Entry(f2, textvariable=queryby).grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=(W, E))


f2labelt1=Label(f2, text="I would like to query ").grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=(W, E))
f2labelt2=Label(f2, text="    from ").grid(column=4, row=3, sticky=(W, E))
f2createmenu() #This is where the subroutine is called from.
```

As can be seen in the picture below, It does appear in a new window when I really want it to appear next to the "from" text. https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrL1s.jpg

Comment: Well, put OptionMenu into the frame you want. You put the OptionMenu into "master" which is a new window instead of "f2". By the way, I see calls to Tk() and mainloop(). Note, that generally you only have one of each in your complete application.

Comment: Would that create the menu inside the same window or as a separate window?

Comment: The first parameter to OptionMenu is "parent". The menu is created within the element you specify there.

Comment: Correct, thank you! All I needed to do was change where it said "parent" to "f2" as that is the frame in which I wanted it. Thank you so much everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show all of your code, but you're clearly doing something wrong. A tkinter application must have exactly one root window. Since you're creating widgets before calling this function, you've either created a root widow or one is being created implicitly prior to calling this function.

This function creates a *second* root window. If you don't want a second root window, don't create an instance of `Tk()` and don't call `mainloop`.

It seems like the simple fix is to pass in the window in which you want the option menu to appear:

```
def f2createmenu(master):

    variable = StringVar(master)
    variable.set("one") # default value

    w = OptionMenu(master, variable, "one", "two", "three")
    w.pack()
```

You would then call it with something like this:

```
f2createmenu(f2)
```